# Более изящное решение для if - elif - else

Tags: python-3.x

Есть два списка авторов. Один с формулой:

```
authors_b = '^AТуранов^BХ. Т.', '^AГордиенко^BА. А.'
```

Другой без:

```
authors_a = 'Туранов Х.Т.', 'Гордиенко А.А.'
```

Ещё есть два словаря с кодами для авторов(один с полным именем автора, другой с инициалами). И там, и там коды абсолютно одинаковые. Выглядит так:

```
full_name_auth = {'Овчинников Игорь Георгиевич': '10002712', 'Алексеева Людмила Модестовна': '10000006', 'Анненкова Капитолина Ивановна': '10000007'}
ini_name = {'Овчинников И. Г.': '10002712', 'Алексеева Л. М.': '10000006', 'Анненкова К. И.': '10000007'}
```

Если у статьи автор один, то он должен попасть в формулу со своим кодом в таком виде:

```
#700: ^310002712^AОвчинников^BИ. Г.
```

Если авторов 2, то первый встает в 700 поле, а второй в 701. Выглядит вот так:

```
#700: ^310002712^AОвчинников^BИ. Г.
#701: ^AШепелева^BИ. О.
```

Если авторов нет в словарях, то он будет без кода. Если авторов 3, то:

```
#700: ^310002712^AОвчинников^BИ. Г.
#701: ^310000006^AАлексеева^BЛ. М.
#701: ^AГузенкова^BЕ. А.
```

Если 4 и больше, то авторы все попадают в 701:

```
#701: ^310002712^AОвчинников^BИ. Г.
#701: ^AСтаценко^BК. А.
#701: ^AГузенкова^BЕ. А.
#701: ^AПахомов^BА. П.
```

Мое решение:

```
    if len_authors == 1:
        if 'Овчинников Игорь Георгиевич' == authors_a[0]:
            print('#700: ^3' + full_name_auth['Овчинников Игорь Георгиевич'] + str(authors_b[0]))
        elif 'Гузенкова Е.А.' == authors_a[0]:
            print('#700: ^3' + ini_name['Гузенкова Е.А.'] + str(authors_b[0]))


    elif len_authors == 2:
        if 'Овчинников Игорь Георгиевич' == authors_a[0]:
            print('#700: ^3' + full_name_auth['Овчинников Игорь Георгиевич'] + str(authors_b[0]))
        elif 'Овчинников И.Г.' == authors_a[0]:
            print('#700: ^3' + full_name_auth['Овчинников Игорь Георгиевич'] + str(authors_b[0]))
        elif 'Осокин Илья Александрович' == authors_a[0]:
            print('#700: ^3' + full_name_auth['Осокин Илья Александрович'] + str(authors_b[0]))
        else:
            print('#700: ' + str(authors_b[0]))

        if 'Овчинников Игорь Георгиевич' == authors_a[1]:
            print('#701: ^3' + full_name_auth['Овчинников Игорь Георгиевич'] + str(authors_b[1]))
        elif 'Овчинников И.Г.' == authors_a[1]:
            print('#701: ^3' + full_name_auth['Овчинников Игорь Георгиевич'] + str(authors_b[1]))
        else:
            print('#701: ' + str(authors_b[1]))

   elif len_authors == 3:
        if 'Овчинников Игорь Георгиевич' == authors_a[0]:
            print('#700: ^3' + full_name_auth['Овчинников Игорь Георгиевич'] + str(authors_b[0]))
        elif 'Овчинников И.Г.' == authors_a[0]:
            print('#700: ^3' + full_name_auth['Овчинников Игорь Георгиевич'] + str(authors_b[0]))
        elif 'Осокин Илья Александрович' == authors_a[0]:
            print('#700: ^3' + full_name_auth['Осокин Илья Александрович'] + str(authors_b[0]))
        else:
                print('#701: ' + str(authors_b[0]))

        if 'Овчинников Игорь Георгиевич' == authors_a[1]:
            print('#701: ^3' + full_name_auth['Овчинников Игорь Георгиевич'] + str(authors_b[1]))
        elif 'Овчинников И.Г.' == authors_a[1]:
            print('#701: ^3' + full_name_auth['Овчинников Игорь Георгиевич'] + str(authors_b[1]))
        elif 'Осокин Илья Александрович' == authors_a[1]:
            print('#701: ^3' + full_name_auth['Осокин Илья Александрович'] + str(authors_b[1]))
        elif 'Юшков Владимир Сергеевич' == authors_a[1]:
            print('#701: ^3' + full_name_auth['Юшков Владимир Сергеевич'] + str(authors_b[1]))
        else:
            print('#701: ' + str(authors_b[1]))

        if 'Овчинников Игорь Георгиевич' == authors_a[2]:
            print('#701: ^3' + full_name_auth['Овчинников Игорь Георгиевич'] + str(authors_b[2]))
        elif 'Овчинников И.Г.' == authors_a[2]:
            print('#701: ^3' + full_name_auth['Овчинников Игорь Георгиевич'] + str(authors_b[2]))
        elif 'Осокин Илья Александрович' == authors_a[2]:
            print('#701: ^3' + full_name_auth['Осокин Илья Александрович'] + str(authors_b[2]))
        elif 'Гузенкова Е.А.' == authors_a[2]:
            print('#701: ^3' + ini_name['Гузенкова Е.А.'] + str(authors_b[2]))
        else:
            print('#701: ' + str(authors_b[2]))
```

И т.д. Проблема заключается в том, что авторов не 1 или 2 штуки, их больше 500. Не хочется их всех вносить в ручную. Подскажите, пожалуйста, более эффективное решение. Заранее благодарна за ответ

Comment: В вашем коде нет логики, описанной выше (Если авторов 2, то первый встает в 700 поле, а второй в 701). А также проверки, есть ли код у автора.

Comment: @vp_arth, код поправила(некорректно скопировала). Подскажите, как сделать логично?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
first_code = '#700' if len(authors) < 4 else '#701'
for idx, author in enumerate(authors):
    code = first_code if idx == 0 else '#701'
    id = get_author_id(author)
    id_str = '^3{}'.format(id) if id else ''
    formula = get_author_formula(author)
    print('{}: {}{}'.format(code, id_str, formula))
```